# Why I can't reassign variables inside a "build" function in the successfully?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextField widget and a ElevatedButton widget in a Container, I want to get the TextField's value when I press the button.So, I declare a variable called "newTaskTitle"

```
class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        String newTaskTitle;
        // return Container().....
}
}
```

inside that Container I have a TextField widget and a ElevatedButton widget like I said, and I try to reassign "newTaskTitle".

```
TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
            onChanged: (value) {
              newTaskTitle = value;
            },
          )
```

and then I print the value when I press the button, but I always get a "null" value.

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print(newTaskTitle);
            },
            )
```

I'm  just following a online course, I' pretty sure I coding like her
[teacher's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FChCn.png)
[teacher's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNRuA.png)

1. his flutter version is 2.1.0 while mine is 3.10.6, is it a problem with the version?
2. I also confused that whether i can change a variable inside a stateless widget.

If you could help me I will appreciate that

Comment: are you getting the value inside the onChanged? try adding a print there.

Comment: Every build() resets any variable declared within build.  And that could be 60 times per second.  To persist values between builds, you need to use some sort of State, like a StatefulWidget, an InheritedWidget, or perhaps a state management solution like Riverpod.

Comment: The only possible reason could be that this stateless widget is being rebuilt by its parent, which triggers its build() again and it gets reset. Maybe there is a setState in the parent widget? Because I see a callback in your teacher's code, somewhere there?

Comment: @MuhammadHussain you are right, this stateless widget's parent is statefulwidget, but teacher's code did work. I don't know where the problem is, and I wonder what action make the parent widget rebuild, I just typed some words and press the button

Comment: @pixel I'm tried to do this and I'm pretty sure I got the value insisde